# One-To-Many Cascade Save, ERROR: null value in column "b_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, one-to-many

When I try to insert using this relationship with cascade capability. The system got error:

> ERROR: null value in column "b_id" violates not-null constraint

A entity.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
private B b;
```

B entity.

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<C> cs;
```

C entity.

```java
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
private B b;
```

Execute.

```java
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    List<C> cs = new ArrayList<C>();
    cs.add(c);

    b.setCs(cs);
    a.setB(b);

    aRepository.save(a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `c` does not know its `b` "parent" - try adding `c.setB(b)` before saving.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do the same as @prptn knowing that `C` primary key is a composite key of `bId` and another field of `C` called `code`. It seems that no binding is made between the `@EmbeddedId` and the `@ManyToOne` of `C` because I still get the error: null value in column "b_id" violates not-null constraint. Any idea?